# MySQL процедуры как не подставлять параметры из JSON в Where если их нет

Tags: mysql, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста как без множества IF ELSE сделать следующее: 
Не добавлять параметры в WHERE.

Есть процедура, которая принимает JSON
    procedure_report(IN inParam JSON)
В JSON может быть несколько значений например: Имя, год, описание, но их может и не быть.

Нужно в таком случае, если например имени нет, не добавлять в WHERE name = @_name

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_report(IN inParam JSON)
    BEGIN

       SET @_name = replace(JSON_EXTRACT(inParam, '$._name'), '\"', '');
       SET @_start_date = replace(JSON_EXTRACT(inParam, '$._start_date'), '\"', '');
       SET @_description = replace(JSON_EXTRACT(inParam, '$._description'), '\"', '');

WITH cte_main_data AS (SELECT
                                                person.person_id         AS person_id,
                                                discipline.discipline_id AS discipline_id,
                                                result.actual_result     AS result,
                                                record.actual_result     AS record

                                         FROM person

                                                INNER JOIN tournament                       
                                                ON tournament.tournament_id = competition_program.tournament_id

 WHERE name = @_name
      AND start_date = @_start_date
      AND description = @_description)
```

Comment: под рукой нет mysql - если параметра нет во входящем json, какое значение присваивается переменной?

Answer (score 0):

Если параметра нет, то в WHERE значения не должно быть

Решение следующиее:

```
 WHERE
(name = @_name OR @_name IS NULL )
AND (start_date = @_start_date OR @_start_date IS NULL)
AND (description = @_description OR @_description IS NULL)
```

Если значение есть, то применится в Where если нет, то не применится.